# How to remove CentOS boot option in BIOS

Tags: linux, centos, boot, bios, bootable

I installed CentOS before and already change to Windows 10 now. But the boot option for the CentOS still in BIOS even after I formatted the hard disk.

[image]

Any fix?

Answer (score 0):

Once in Windows you can use the `bcdedit /v` command from the command line to view all current entries.

Find the identifier for the CentOS boot option and run the command `bcdedit /delete {identifier}`

*Note that you must run CMD as administrator to use bcdedit*